# Why does HTML not appear as an Email creation option in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, content-builder

I am trying to create an email using HTML paste, I know this option is available as I've used it before however this particular MID doesn't have the option available.

[image]

Is this something that needs to be enabled somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I have experienced as well. Easiest solution is to put in a helpdesk ticket to SFMC Global Support. They will need to enable a permission on their end and that should allow you to have access to that option.